# Need Guidance for django wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

currently i'm trying to Integrating Wagtail with existing django project.

I'm new in wagtail, and still learning about wagtail

```
class BlogPage(Page):
body = RichTextField(blank=True)
categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
location = models.ForeignKey('blog.Location', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

and then i register the category and the location model as snippets.

how's the best practice for build page contains of BlogPage with 
certain category / location ?

and how to call that page from django's menu

or maybe where can i find documentation for integrating wagtail to existing django project

Thank you

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo it has an example of how to setup navigation https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/base/templatetags/navigation_tags.py . Your listing page can be a new page type with additional context (the queryset that provides items for a listing) here is an example http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context

Comment: Thanks @allcaps i'm gonna check that link. one more question is it possible to use class based view inside wagtail to make form ?

Comment: Wagtail is on top op Django, so you can use regular Django routes and views. But if you like it to be a view in Wagtail page tree you have to add your Django form to the Wagtail Page context. In the same way you add the qs for the listing or any other var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a Blog Listing Page, where you can list all your blog posts and then have blog posts based on a certain category.

You'll probably want to use a RoutablePageMixin (if you're not creating an SPA with Vue or React). A RoutablePageMixin lets you automatically create additional child pages, without having to create Wagtail child pages.

```
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route


class BlogListingPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    """BlogListingPage class."""

    template = 'cms/blog/blog_listing_page.html'
    subpage_types = ['pages.BlogPage']

    # ... other fields here

    @route(r'^category/(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]*)/$', name='category_list')
    def category_list(self, request, cat_slug):
        """Return posts in a certain category."""
        context = self.get_context(request)
        posts = BlogPage.objects.live().filter(categories__slug=cat_slug).order_by('-pub_date')
        context['posts'] = posts
        return render(request, 'cms/blog/blog_category_page.html', context)
```

**Note** I did *not* test this code, you may need to fix any errors and adjust this for your needs.

The above code will take your blog listing page (say its localhost:8000/blog/) and create a category listing page (ie. localhost:8000/blog/category/topic-slug/)

That `topic-slug` will be passed into the `category_list()` method, where you can then filter your BlogPage's based on the category(ies) it's in. It will add `posts` to your page, and render a different listing page, where you can customize your template.

It's been a while since I checked, but the [Wagtail Bakery Demo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo) probably has examples of this in there (and a lot of really sweet goodies).

You can read more about Wagtail Routable Pages at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/routablepage.html as well.

Comment: Thanks Kalob, i'm gonna try apply this method and check the reference. btw is it possible to use class based view inside wagtail to make a CreateView ?

Comment: Are you creating a CreateView inside of the /admin/, or in your templates? If its inside the admin, Wagtail comes with helper classes to help you customize all those. If it's inside your templates, you can use a `forms.Form` model and inside your `get_context()` method add the form (`context["form"] = YourForm(request.POST or None)`). Wagtail does processing in its `serve()` method, so check for POST submissions and process the form in there.

Comment: something like this 
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/15/wagtail-2-steps-adding-pages-outside-cms/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52512545/is-it-possible-to-use-class-based-view-instead-of-function-based-view-wagtail
but with class based view