# is it possible to use class based view instead of function based view wagtail?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, wagtail

i'm still struggling to integrate django wagtail to an existing project.

i'm only using wagtail for my blog page. and i want to create a form to create new post for my blog from my wagtail page. the way i create this is using an routablepage. here's some of my code

i'm using [this](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2016/02/15/wagtail-2-steps-adding-pages-outside-cms/) as my reference

models.py

```
class BlogIndex(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    ...

    @route(r'^send-post/$', name='send_posts')
    def submit(self, request):
        from .views import submit_news
        return submit_news(request, self)
    ...

class BlogPage(Page):
    ...
```

forms.py

```
class NewsPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
```

views.py

```
def submit_blog(request, blog_index):
    ...
```

is it possible to change submit_blog function into create view ?
because i've tried to make create view before and try something like this but it doesn't work because it will recursive to call the BlogPage Page in models.py

models.py

```
class BlogIndex(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
...

    @route(r'^send-post/$', BlogCreate.as_view(), name='send_posts')
```

views.py

```
class BlogCreate(CreateView):
...
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're nearly there, but `@route` needs to decorate a view function (rather than passing the view as a decorator parameter).

Try this:

```
class BlogIndex(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
...
    @route(r'^send-post/$', name='send_posts'):
    def submit(self, request):
        blog_create_view = BlogCreate.as_view()

        return blog_create_view(request, self)
```

instead of:

```
class BlogIndex(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
...

    @route(r'^send-post/$', BlogCreate.as_view(), name='send_posts')
```